# Wrong approach or Wrong OOP design?

Tags: oop, java-8

Following is my code isolation.

> Interactable Interface.

```
public interface Interactable <E extends Interactable> {

    List<Person> personsInteracting = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Person> personsWaiting     = new ArrayList<>();

    long INTERACTION_TIME = 5 * 60;

    default int getNumberOfPeopleInteracting () {
        return personsInteracting.size();
    }

    default int getNumberOfPeopleWaiting () {
        return personsWaiting.size();
    }

    boolean isMultipleActionsAllowed ();

    boolean isFurtherActionsAllowed ();

    public abstract boolean tryOccupiedBy (final Person person, final Interactions interaction)
        throws InteractionNotPossibleException;

    E getObject ();

    EnumSet<Interactions> getInteractions ();
}
```

> InteractiveObject Abstract Class

```
public abstract class InteractiveObject implements Interactable {

    protected final String       name;
    protected       int          numberOfSimultaneousInteractions;
    protected       Interactions currentInteraction;

    public InteractiveObject (final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMultipleActionsAllowed () {
        return numberOfSimultaneousInteractions > 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFurtherActionsAllowed () {
        return personsInteracting.isEmpty() ||
               (getNumberOfPeopleInteracting() > numberOfSimultaneousInteractions);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryOccupiedBy (final Person person, final Interactions interaction)
        throws InteractionNotPossibleException {
        boolean isOccupied = false;
        if (!isFurtherActionsAllowed()) {
            throw new InteractionNotPossibleException(this + " is already in use by some other " +
                                                      "person.");
        }
        personsInteracting.add(person);
        currentInteraction = interaction;
        return isOccupied;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumberOfSimultaneousInteractions () {
        return numberOfSimultaneousInteractions;
    }
}
```

> Chair (One of the child class)

```
public class Chair extends InteractiveObject {

    private final EnumSet<Interactions> INTERACTIONS = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(
        new Interactions[] {Interactions.DRAG, Interactions.SIT}));

    public Chair (final String objectName) {
        super(objectName);
        super.numberOfSimultaneousInteractions = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Interactable getObject () {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<Interactions> getInteractions () {
        return INTERACTIONS;
    }
}
```

Here is the piece of code that executes and brings the problem, this question is asked for.

```
        final InteractiveObject chair1  = new Chair("Chair1");
        final Person            person1 = new Person("Person1");
        final Room              room    = new Room("Room1", 2, 2);
        room.personEnters(person1);
        room.putObject(chair1);
        person1.tryOccupying(chair1);
```

Above piece of code, successfully occupies the chair object. Now,

```
        final InteractiveObject chair2  = new Chair("Chair2");
        final Person            person2 = new Person("Person2");
        final Room              room2    = new Room("Room2", 2, 2);
        room2.personEnters(person2);
        room2.putObject(chair2);
        person2.tryOccupying(chair2);
```

This piece of code doesn't let the `person2` occupy since my code states that 1 person is already interacting with `chair2`, where as no one is interacting with it.

> Solution of my problem:

I moved my List of `personInteracting` to `InteractiveObject` and function `tryOccupiedBy` to each child class and everything works fine.

> **Questions:**

1. I put `personsInteracting` in Interactable interface since I believe that every future implementation of Interactable will have it. Developers won't have to implement themselves. (But perhaps this idea seems to be wrong)
2. If `tryOccupiedBy` function has same implementation, what is the purpose of whole OOP?
3. I now know that the isolation was wrong and I know where to place the pieces to get the results. But can someone kindly point me out about some OOP concept which I did not understand and should be implemented in a much better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` keyword was not added to the Java language to do the kind of thing which you seem to be trying to achieve. Data defined in an interface is intended to be constant - the modifiers 'public static' are automatically applied to any field definitions in an interface. If you create a `default` method in the interface then it must either be stateless or act directly only on purely statically available state. Default methods can call other interface methods to modify instance state, .

By placing `personsInteracting` field in the interface, you made the same instance common to every object implementing that interface, and so your `tryOccupying` method was acting on purely global state.

So, the purpose of having `default` methods in the Java language is to support adding new methods to interfaces in a backwards compatible fashion, nothing more. You shouldn't reuse it as a generic form of code re-use - it was never intended for that and you'll get (as you did) weird behaviour.

You didn't *have* to put `tryOccupiedBy` in the child classes, however, so you didn't *have* to have a load of duplicated code. You could still declare the method signature in the interface (which is what interfaces are generally supposed to do) and then implement the common method in your abstract base class. By putting the data fields in the base class, you make them *instance* fields and so they are not shared between objects.

```
public interface Interactable <E extends Interactable> {
    ...
    boolean tryOccupiedBy (final Person person, final Interactions interaction)
        throws InteractionNotPossibleException;
    ...
}

public abstract class InteractiveObject implements Interactable {
    private final List<Person> personsInteracting = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Person> personsWaiting     = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    @Override
    public final boolean tryOccupiedBy (final Person person, final Interactions interaction)
        throws InteractionNotPossibleException {
        boolean isOccupied = false;
        if (!isFurtherActionsAllowed()) {
            throw new InteractionNotPossibleException(this + " is already in use by some other " +
                                                      "person.");
        }
        personsInteracting.add(person);
        currentInteraction = interaction;
        return isOccupied;
    }
    ...
}
```